# sistema de factura html y javascript

Tags: javascript, html

hola compañeros acudo a su gran experiencia para compartir una duda y me puedan brindar una ayudita pues tengo un sistema de facturacion y necesito agregar un campo que me permita calcular un descuento sobre  el valor de los productos mas no a todo el total de la factura no manejo muy bien aun el javascript

quedo muy agradecida

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){b=i-1;
        $('#addr'+i).html($('#addr'+b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i+1);
        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++; 
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i>1){
        $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
        i--;
        }
        calc();
    });
    
    $('#tab_logic tbody').on('keyup change',function(){
        calc();
    });
    $('#tax').on('keyup change',function(){
        calc_total();
    });
    

});

function calc()
{
    $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
        var html = $(this).html();
        if(html!='')
        {
            var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
            var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
            $(this).find('.total').val(qty*price);
            
            calc_total();
        }
    });
}

function calc_total()
{
    total=0;
    $('.total').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sub_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
    tax_sum=total/100*$('#tax').val();
    $('#tax_amount').val(tax_sum.toFixed(2));
    $('#total_amount').val((tax_sum+total).toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center"> # </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Product </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Qty </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Price </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Total </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name='product[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='Enter Qty' class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='Enter Unit Price' class="form-control price" step="0.00" min="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</button>
      <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="pull-right col-md-4">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic_total">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Sub Total</th>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='sub_total' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" id="sub_total" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Tax</th>
            <td class="text-center"><div class="input-group mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tax" placeholder="0">
                <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
              </div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Tax Amount</th>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='tax_amount' id="tax_amount" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Grand Total</th>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='total_amount' id="total_amount" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que estoy entendiendo un poco, pero aclárame una duda, básicamente lo que quieres es que el descuento se agregue sólo al producto que estás añadiendo más no al total. Por ejemplo, el total de la factura va en 300$ y agregas un producto en 100$ con un descuento del 50%, ese 50% sólo irá al producto de 100$ para que el total de la factura ahora de 350$, ¿cierto?

Comment: si si eso es exactamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto aplica descuento sobre cada producto de forma individual. He añadido el campo `dto` y luego en la función `calc()` restamos al precio de producto el descuento.

**Cambio**

Creamos una variable `descuento` donde convertimos en decimal el número introducido para luego restarlo al precio.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){b=i-1;
        $('#addr'+i).html($('#addr'+b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i+1);
        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++; 
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i>1){
        $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
        i--;
        }
        calc();
    });
    
    $('#tab_logic tbody').on('keyup change',function(){
        calc();
    });
    $('#tax').on('keyup change',function(){
        calc_total();
    });
    

});

function calc()
{
    $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
        var html = $(this).html();
        if(html!='')
        {
            var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
      var dto = $(this).find('.dto').val();
            var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
      var descuento = price*(dto/100);
            $(this).find('.total').val((qty*price)-descuento);
            
            calc_total();
        }
    });
}

function calc_total()
{
    total=0;
    $('.total').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sub_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
    tax_sum=total/100*$('#tax').val();
    $('#tax_amount').val(tax_sum.toFixed(2));
    $('#total_amount').val((tax_sum+total).toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center"> # </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Product </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Qty </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Dto </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Price </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Total </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name='product[]'  placeholder='Enter Product Name' class="form-control"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='Enter Qty' class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='dto[]' placeholder='Enter Dto' class="form-control dto" step="0" min="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='Enter Unit Price' class="form-control price" step="0.00" min="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</button>
      <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="pull-right col-md-4">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic_total">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Sub Total</th>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='sub_total' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" id="sub_total" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Tax</th>
            <td class="text-center"><div class="input-group mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tax" placeholder="0">
                <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
              </div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Tax Amount</th>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='tax_amount' id="tax_amount" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Grand Total</th>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='total_amount' id="total_amount" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hola gracias por tomarte tu tiempo pero alli solo restariamos el valor dentro del campo dto mas no el % seria como esta en el escript cantidad*precio/100*dto

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es descontar utilizando porcentajes?

Comment: si exactamente quiero que cuando por ejemplo yo ponga cantidad 1 y precio 490000 y si agrego un dto de 25% el total sea 367500 que seria la resta del dto y el valor del producto y si tengo otro producto cantidad 2 por ejemplo y su valor sea 10000 el total en ese producto son 20mil y el valor total seria la suma de estos 3 productos 387500

Comment: Ya lo tienes. En el campo descuento no tienes que poner el simbolo % , solo escribir el número de descuento

Comment: gracias son la mejor comunidad